# Conditional DynamoDB update not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a silent auction site. My Lambda function should update an item *under the condition that the submitted bid > current high bid.* However, the condition does not seem to be applying; the update occurs even if the submitted bid is less than the current high bid. 
**Please help me identify what I'm doing wrong:**

##My DynamoDB table looks like this:##

- Table name: SilentAuction2
- Primary partition key: ItemID (String)
- other attributes:

  - CurrentHighBid (Number)
  - HighestBidder (String)
  - Notes (String)
  - BidHistoryBids (List)
  - BidHistoryPPL (List)

My condition, as stated above, is that the incoming event.NewBid is greater than the CurrentHighBid. Here is the Lambda code in Node.JS:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});

exports.handler = function index(event, context, callback) {
        var table = "SilentAuction2";

var ItemID = event.ItemID;
var NewBid = event.NewBid;
var NewBidder = event.NewBidder;
var Notes = event.Notes;

var params = {
    TableName:table,
    Key:{
        "ItemID": ItemID
},
  //update and append values      
UpdateExpression: "SET #BidList = list_append(#BidList, :hb),
                       #PplList = list_append(#PplList, :hp),
                       CurrentHighBid =:c, 
                       HighestBidder=:h, 
                       Notes=:n",
  //condition on which to update if true
ConditionalExpression: " :c > CurrentHighBid",

ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#BidList" : "BidHistoryBids",
      "#PplList" : "BidHistoryPPL"
  },

ExpressionAttributeValues:{
     ":hb":[NewBid],
     ":hp":[NewBidder],
     ":n":Notes,
     ":c":NewBid,
     ":h":NewBidder

        }, 
ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
    };

docClient.update(params, function(err, data){
     if(err){
          callback(err, null);
     }else{
          callback(null, data);
            }
     });
};
```

This links were helpful in researching ConditionalExpression within DynamoDB:
https://egkatzioura.com/2016/08/09/update-dynamodb-items-with-node-js/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.05

Comment: CurrentHighBid is attribute name not value

Comment: @MilanRakos Yes I figured this was the issue, but how do I reference the value for attribute CurrentHighBid within the ConditionalExpression?

Comment: you need to read from DB CurrentHighBid value

Comment: and how do you read from DB?